# Postgresql - slow distinct on million records table

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, distinct

I have a table with a million of records, i need to select the distinct values of log_type.
In other queries i also need to filter log_types result of the distinct and limit the result.
But the query is really slow, also this simple one

```
select distinct log_type
from app_logs;
```

log_type has an index but nothing change without index, query always use Seq Scan

This is the explain

```
Aggregate (cost) 119007.80 - 119008.03 (rows) 29 (time) 1923.251
|- Seq Scan (cost) 0.00 - 115796.84 (rows) 1284384  (time) 1300.025
```

I read other posts but not helped me to find a solution (if exists).

There is any way to improve the performace?
Maybe the only my solution is cache the complete distinct results in server application.

ps. i can't define custom functions on db server

Comment: Get better hardware I guess. Although I must say `log_type` sound much like an enum,  and I would expect `select distinct log_type` to return more or less the same result each time.

Comment: log_type can be created dynamically, i can't define a enum with prefixed values.

I have slow performance also in others db not only on my local instance with poor hardware and i don't think that this can be reduced to an hardware issue.

Comment: And how many distinct `log_type` values do you have? How often do you update the table statistics?

Comment: now log_type have 30 distinct values
i don't know the frequence of statistics, i think threre is the default setting of postgresql